# detecting and extracting circles from image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have multiple files which has many sub circled images in it.
My task is to automatically detect and extract the circled images and save as separate files.
Could anyone provide an example or the code for the same either using Matlabs or any other software.

Comment: Can you provide a sample image?

Answer (score 1):

The Image Processing Toolbox in MATLAB provides the function [`imfindcircles`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) which should do what you are looking for.

A generic code example:

```
[img] = imread('my_img.tiff');
radius_range = [10, 40] % range of radii from 10 to 40 pixels
[centres, radii] = imfindcircles(img, radius);
```

... or with specifying more parameters (see [doc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html#bta7gun-3))

```
[centres, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(img, ....
     [10, 40], ...                  % range of radii from 10 to 40 pixels
     'ObjectPolarity','bright', ... % are objects bright or dark?
     'Method','TwoStage', ...       % algorithm: TwoStage or PhaseCode
     'Sensitivity', 0.96 ...        % the higher the more circular objects it'll find
);
```

To visualize the result you can do:

```
imshow(img); hold on;
plot(centres(:,1), centres(:,2), 'r*');         % plot circle centers
viscircles(centres, radii, 'EdgeColor', 'b');   % plot circles
```